# CodePipeline Executes Before CodeBuildAction Role is Created

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

CDK Version: 1.108.0
Node Version: v12.16.1

I am creating a CodePipeline via `new Pipeline()` and passing standard props for a `CodeCommitSource` and `CodeBuildAction` constructs. I am **not** providing a role for `Pipeline` or `CodeBuildAction`. I do however, add a few permissions to the underlying `Pipeline` role after instantiation via

```
myPipeline.role.grantPrincipal.addToPrincipalPolicy(...)
```

What I'm observing is that the CodeBuild IAM Role intended for CodePipeline to assume and execute `StartBuild` on the CodeBuild Project is created by CloudFormation **after** the CodePipeline. This results in the CodePipeline executing and failing on 1st run. Re-executing the pipeline succeeds but when attempting to automate a deployment which starts from deploying a pipeline this behavior is not ideal. Is this a known issue or something that I may be seeing due to some mis-configuration?

Comment: The order of operations isn't clear to me. Are you running CDK in the pipeline that affects the pipeline itself?

Comment: I've seen it before in straight Cloudformation with the role defined in the same template but lived with it as it allowed me to visualize the pipeline first before running and I've caught a few issues that way. I assumed I could use a DependsOn attribute with the pipeline depending on the role to solve it.

Comment: @jonlegend I'm running `cdk deploy` on the pipeline stack. The stack creates the CodePipeline which includes a CodeBuildAction. The Default Policy for the CodeBuildAction is created by Cfn after the successful creation of the CodePipeline. When the CodePipeline is created, it immediately executes against the target branch and fails on the CodeBuild Stage because the policy which is assumes to execute `codebuild:StartBuild`hasn't been created

Comment: @RonanCunningham I tried something like `codepipeline.role.node.addDependency(codebuildRole)` but that for some reason or another just failed to deploy.

Comment: On reflection, the pipeline will implicitly depend on the project which will implicitly depend on the role so DependsOn should not be needed in a single template, What region are you deploying to? The only thing I can think of and even then it is only a vague thought is that the role is global and will get created in us-east-1 ( I think ) and something about a single cloudformation template deploying a role to us-east-1 and a codebuild project and pipeline to another region may break with the IAM role creation being asynchronous in that context rather than synchronous (?)